# Does every member in Hyperledger-Fabric Network have their own copy State Database?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

As per my understanding of **Hyperledger-Fabric**, Ledger consists of two components **1) Transaction Log Chain** & **2) State Database**. So, Everybody maintains their own copy of **Transaction Log Chain** as it will small in size, but my question is does they maintain such separate copy of **State Database** as well or they share central State Database? As it will be large in size because it contains actual data and consume lot space on each node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Peers maintain the ledger and state database for any channels they have joined.

When a peer joins a channel, it will receive all the blocks for that channel.  It will then validate all of the transactions in each block and commit the state change(s) for all valid transactions.  Blocks are stored in a file-based ledger and the latest value for any given state key is stored in the state database.  There is currently no setting which allows you to configure the peer to only store the ledger and not the state.

As an additional note, peers which do not have chaincode installed will still store the valid state associated with the chaincode in its state database.

Comment: I'm not sure why this received a -1 ... the answer was correct ... I've rewritten the response to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks - Gari Singh  for explaination.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I deleted the incorrect answer.